# Google's quickstart.py not connecting to Google Workspace API because of JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I am following the steps in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python to create their example application that can print a Gmail user's labels. I get `JSONDecodeError: Extra data` instead when I execute `quickstart.py`. See **The Error** below.

The ultimate goal is to automate emailing invoices. However, I'm not familiar with the underlying concepts and without a working example I'm especially unclear on how to proceed.

### Original Question

Any suggestions on either a) how to fix the issue or b) better resources with which to learn the concepts involved?

### Resolution

*When I deleted an extraneous `ND` found at the end of the `credentials.json` file, the `JSONDecoderError` problem disappeared. I don't know how it got there; presumably, the error was mine.*

### Follow-up comments

@DaImTo pointed out in their answer that the tutorial's example code is for installed applications and that "for google workspace automation you would want to use a service account and configure domain wide delegation to say a dummy user on your workspace account". See their answer for a slightly more in-depth explanation and suggested code for service account authorisation.

After correcting the `credentials.json` file, a new issue presented itself. I will not go into that issue here since, as per @DaImTo's answer, the tutorial is not the correct template for creating google workspace automation.

### Future Updates

I will update how I progress with @DaImTo's suggestions; either here in the question body or as a comment or link.

### The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miranda and Warren\Documents\Invoice\Invoicing\quickstart.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Miranda and Warren\Documents\Invoice\Invoicing\quickstart.py", line 30, in main
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
  File "C:\Users\Miranda and Warren\Documents\Invoice\Invoicing\NDIS\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 205, in from_client_secrets_file
    client_config = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 406 (char 405)
```

### The Tutorial Code

The quickstart.py code I copied and pasted from their start up guide is reproduced below:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
            return
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I followed the steps for "Authorize credentials for a desktop application". The following redacted JSON is what I had on my machine. Note the 'ND' at the end of the file.

### (Invalid) contents of credentials.json

```js
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "[46 characters here].apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "ndis-automation",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "[6 characters]-[7 characters]-[20 characters]",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost"]
  }
}ND
```

Comment: Did you follow the directions and create "Authorize credentials for a desktop application"?

Comment: I did follow the directions for "Authorise credentials for a deskstop application". But upon examination of `credentials.json`, I seem to have somehow introduced invalid characters at the end of the file. That is my current surmise at least.

Answer (score 1):

## Extra data: line 1 column 406

Is probably caused by an invalid credentials.json file it would be interesting to see what it looks like.

## What your question should have been

> The ultimate goal is to automate emailing invoices.

If you want to use gmail automated with google workspace, then that tutoiral is not going to help you.

The authorization method in that tutorial is for installed applications.  For google workspace automation you would want to use a service account and configure [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) to say a dummy user on your workspace account.

The code for service account authorization is different, and you need to set the subject to the user on your domain which you have configured delegation for.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                        credentials_file,
                        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])

impersonate = 'no-reply@daimto.com'

credentials = credentials.with_subject(impersonate)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: I added a redacted copy-paste of `credentials.json` to the question body. There was an extraneous 'ND' at the end of the file. Once removed, `quickstart.py` executed past the JSONDecoderError breakpoint. I still failed to have the tutorial's intended result but I won't investigate that further. Instead, I will follow-up on your suggestion for google workspace automation.